no sound from Vox vx1 amp without headphones plugged in
I have a Vox VX1 practice amp that was given to me. when I play through the headphones, everything works and the amp settings all adjust as they should. However, when I remove the headphones from the jack, there is no sound at all, no buzzing, humming, nothing. is it the speaker or the headphone jack?

First port of call would be the headphone socket itself. It's a switched socket, which switches the speaker off when the headphones are connected. Try some switch cleaner, and plug/unplug the jack many times to remove any dirt that may be stopping the switch actually working. May need to get inside, to scrape the connections clean.

If the speaker were disconnected or damaged the symptoms would be the same.

@JohnBelzaguy - true, hence the 1st port of call, which may be the cause of the 'speaker being disconnected'. The similar problem occurs on some amps which have send/return sockets, and the switched sockets don't do their job properly.

My point is it might have nothing to do with that, it could simply be a broken or disconnected speaker wire. You’re only considering one option. The first time I would do is check the speaker connection to the amp.

@JohnBelzaguy - sounds like a viable answer.

Most likely culprit is the headphone jack. Give that a good clean first. Then look for other wires come astray. But that doesn't usually happen spontaneously.
Were you given it because it was broken?  :-)
